# Python script to compare value from sql query output with excel cell value

Tags: python, sql-server, excel

I am trying to automate some of my work. I would want to compare value from sql query output with excel cell value using a python script.

I need to check if sql output is greater than excel cell value. If value is greater then execute batch file

Below is the code that I have. However this code executes the batch file even if the sql output value matches the excel cell value.

```
import openpyxl
import pyodbc
import os


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\a_a_s\Desktop\TEST\TEST.xlsx')
worksheet_names = wb.sheetnames 
sheet_index = worksheet_names.index('Sheet2') 
wb.active = sheet_index 
sheet = wb.active
x1 = sheet['A2'].value



conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=NIN.AM.NIC.OMC;"
                      "Database=SOE;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select max(fweek) from AF.NEWDATA")
WEEK = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    

if x1 != WEEK:
        print(WEEK)
        print(x1)   
        os.system(r'C:\Users\ASH\Desktop\TEST\REFRESH.BAT')
       
else:
 print("Latest data already available in report")
 print(WEEK)
 print(x1)
```

Comment: what do you get if you `print(WEEK)`?

Comment: Visually compare the outputs of `print(x1)` and `print(WEEK)` - you don't include them in your question. It's possible that `sheet['A2'].value` is a string and you'd have to `x1 = int(x1)` to make it comparable with the `WEEK` value returned from SQL Server.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning , I have added x1 = int(x1) this to the code and its working fine now. Thank you.